# What's the name for an object (not a curtain or tint) placed on a car window to reduce the sun exposure?

Tags: word-request

What's the name for an object (not a curtain or tint) placed on a car window to reduce the sun exposure?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Car window sunshade protector

[image]

or simply

> [Car shades](https://www.carshades.co.uk/)

When I googled [car blinds](https://www.google.com/search?q=car%20blinds%20meaning&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01DotBoMfJRI1vpAg9nHKZdRZAuvw%3A1623272571949&ei=eyzBYPmzOciDjLsPzbKGiAk&oq=car%20blinds%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BggAEAcQHjoICAAQCBAHEB5QrPwEWJKABWDihAVoAHACeACAAZYIiAGbCpIBBTQuNy0xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi53ZjIuYvxAhXIAWMBHU2ZAZEQ4dUDCA8&uact=5) I also came across

> Car Window Sunshades & Blinds

Comment: I think this good answer illustrates the difference between a "name" and a "description".

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time recently trying to find the most popular name for these and settled on "Car sunshade". However, it's a pretty even split between that and "Car window shade". See [my blog](https://mattburns.co.uk/blog/2022/03/02/hands-on-car-sunshade-comparison-2022/).

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! I've made it more explicit that it's your own blog, see our [Help Center](/help/promotion) for details.